# Building Email app in kitkat

Tags: java, android

There are 2 folders in android kitkat
1. aosp/Package/apps/Email
2. aosp/Package/apps/UnifiedEmail

this is our code in aosp/Package/apps/UnifiedEmail/src/com/android/mail/ui/ThumbnailLoadTask.java 
`decrypt = client.decrypt(fd.getFileDescriptor(), true, mimeType);`

I am able to build UnifildEmail like below,
$Package/apps/UnifiedEmail> mm .
this is creating UnifiedEmail.apk

If I build Email.apk like this in $Package/apps/Email>mm .
I am getting error like below:
`packages/apps/Email/./../Package/apps/UnifiedEmail/src/com/android/mail/ui/ThumbnailLoadTask.java:136: cannot file symbol
symbol : method decrypt(java.io.FileDescriptor,boolean,java.lang.String);
location: class android.st.Client
    decryptBuffer = client.decrypt(fd.getFileDescriptor(), true, mimeType);`
                          *

decrypt method we used in other apps like Galley2, mms etc. there it is working fine.

Can anybody know what might be the reason.

Comment: Changing LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 18 to LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current worked for me. But still don't know how it is related. Can anybody explain?